# Get the earliest date in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following LINQ in a WebAPI controller:

```
MyDate = i.Products.FirstOrDefault().Date
```

It works as expected. But, Products is a Collection, so there can be many dates. The above just selects the first one.

What I really want to do is to find the date, with the earliest time, and select that one.

How would that look?

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` can return null. Your code is vulnerable to NullReferenceExceptions when doing `.Date`. Review it for the case where the list of products is empty. Also take care with the answer you use, test it with an empty list - the same problem will most likely exist there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you only want the date and not the whole product, it's a little clearer to use `Max` or `Min`.

```
MyDate = i.Products.Select(x => x.Date).Max()
```

If you actually want the product, you'll need to sort by the date and then select the first one.

```
MyProduct = i.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Ordering is an expensive operation and should not be used when not necessary.
Your query for the product with the least recent date could be written as `Product oldestProduct = i.Products.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Date == i.Products.Min(y=>y.Date));` or `DateTime minDate = i.Products.Min(x => x.Date);
            Product oldestProduct = i.Products.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Date == minDate);` **Note:** The latter version is more readable but needs two separate queries.

Comment: @SørenD.Ptæus the cost of ordering depends on how the ordering is done. If it's accessing a database and there's an ordered index on the date then it would be pretty cheap.

Comment: Take care: doing `.Max()` or `.Min()` on an empty collection will throw an exception!

Comment: @SørenD.Ptæus Beware that `SingleOrDefault` will thrown an exception if multiple items in the list have the same date value and it matches the `Min` value.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Good point. Although identical date values are quiet unlikely for time stamps I agree using `SingleOrDefault` leaves a chance for errors. If `Date` is not a time stamp but just a date without distinctive `Ticks` values or any other time information the scenario you describe is indeed a real issue and `FirstOrDefault` makes a much better option here.

Answer (score 4):

This way is more concise:

```
var earlyDate = i.Products.Min(p=>p.Date);
```

But you are sure that `Product != null`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 i.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date;
```

Comment: This will give you the largest (recent) date

Comment: There is no *OrderByAscending*

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a lambda expression that will give you the minimum (earliest) date

```
DateTime earliestDate = i.Products.Min(p => p.Date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, if you need earliest use `OrderBy` and need oldest then use `OrderByDescending`.

```cs
 i.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
 i.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply order by date:

```
MyDate = i.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimized way would be :

```
i.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date;
```

It has to be orderby and not orderbydescending. orderbydescending will give you the latest date first and order by will give you the earliest date first.